# Are there simple unsolved problems in statistics?

Tags: statistics, open-problem

In number theory, calculus and various fields of mathematics, there are many unsolved problems.

But are there simple unsolved problems in statistics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the probability that the sun will rise tomorrow?

The [sunrise problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem) is such an open statistics question. As far as I know, there are [22 unsolved problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_statistics) in statistics.

> Difficulties in identifying problems have delayed statistics far more than difficulties in solving problems.

Comment: Maybe a valid and good answer but I feel like the problems are " nonsense ". Like funny psuedoparadoxes and confusions. A bit like the unexpected hanging paradox or the monty hall confusion. For instance the two envellope problem can easily be solved.

Comment: Fair enough, I and most mathematicians would agree with you there. Statistics just doesn't really have open problems.

Comment: Hmm I upvoted your comment and I agree. However Tommy1729 and Sheldon started a " new direction " in a kind of breed between complex analysis and regression. It has open problems.  It is called fake function theory. But for standard statistics I agree.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own question here involving that! :-)

Comment: Im not sure if that is a good idea. Some persons and subjects are controversial. Like tetration and tommy1729... On the other you suggested it so i can blame you :)

Comment: Also it may be easy to solve ... Not many people have looked at it. Maybe crosspost as a new question too ?

Comment: http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=863                                        http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=162&page=2   TPID 17